# Problems using IIF and datepart functions in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, service, reporting

I am having a lot of trouble using IIF and other functions in SQL Reporting Services and when using an expression on a label.

I need to show the day before when running a report with the exception that when it is "Monday", it shows "Saturday" rather than Sunday.

Below is what I am using and it is not working properly as it shows Sunday when I run it today

```
=IIF(
(WeekDayName(WeekDay(dateadd("d", - 1, Today()) )) ="Monday" ), WeekDayName ( WeekDay(dateadd("d", -2, Today()) )) , WeekDayName ( WeekDay(dateadd("d", -1, Today()) )))
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the true part and make it static

```
=IIF( (WeekDayName(WeekDay(dateadd("d", - 1, Today()) )) ="Monday" ),"Saturday", WeekDayName ( WeekDay(dateadd("d", -1, Today()) )))
```

**if it's not working then just let me know so I could give another solution :)**

Comment: I tested the solution, but it does not work as it is just giving me the previous day. I modified the -1 to a -2 in the second portion of the expression and it works great, =IIF( (WeekDayName(WeekDay(dateadd("d", - 1, Today()) )) ="Monday" ),"Saturday", WeekDayName ( WeekDay(dateadd("d", -2, Today()) )))   Thanks a lot for the help